# Selector materiel-ui Partial view of options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am interested in using a materiel-ui selector component or an autocomplete component

I want to let the user choose a number from one to a hundred

But I want him to be presented with options in the first step by skipping dozens (for example 10,20,30, etc.)

After the user selects or types a number he will be able to select the specific number (for example after typing 3 he will be able to select 35)

[image]
[image]

Would appreciate help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocomplete automatically does the filtering for you. This is the simplest use case: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-6fmtv?file=/demo.js:307-318

Comment: But he shows me all options
I want him to show me only the tens!

Comment: that depends on your code. you can pass any arbitrary data you'd like: `new Array(10).fill(1).map((item,index) => item * (index + 1))` . Also you can pass in custom filter algorithm as `filterOptions`. see more on `https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/`

Comment: Thanks for the reference :)
Can you attach a small sample code to use the ``filterOptions``
for my use case?

Comment: Yep. here yours https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-6fmtv?file=/demo.js:315-326

Comment: ``filterOptions`` Not used the link sent

Comment: Oops! Sorry wrong link. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-tjwqs?file=/demo.js